# I am looking for a test CC number that will fail for certain dollar amounts/range

Tags: testing, credit-card

I am using Chase PaymenTech for my credit card processing. I am well aware of the typical test numbers that will work at all times. And I am aware of test numbers I can use that will fail all of the time. What I am looking for is a **test** credit card number that will work for my initial test of a dollar or less but then fail (receive a Do Not Honor status) when testing a charge of a much high dollar amount.

Anyone aware of such a test CC number and what dollar amounts would fail?

Comment: Well, on any development platform I've worked on, you'd use a mock of some kind to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such test card numbers do not exist. If you wanted to test your system in such a manner you would need to design your own tests that would cause it to fail this way.